# Why HTML5 drag and drop dragImage is not displayed when it's hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have faced a problem when setting up *'dragImage'* in HTML5 drag and drop as *div* element.
The problem is that when helper - 1st argument of *setDragImage(helper, x, y)* function is not presented in the dom or is hidden, it's not visible when 'dragstart' event is fired.
Have a look at my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AemN5/10/

> In the fiddle I am rendering helper (it's colored into yellow), than
>   try to drag green draggable box, helper is attached to the mouse when
>   drag starts. However, try to click on the button above the helper to
>   hide helper. Than try again dragging green draggable box - no helper
>   is attached to my mouse.

Any thoughts why it's happening and more important **how to solve the problem?** As my main goal is to have invisible helper and only when user start dragging make it visible attached to the cursor.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible solution http://jsfiddle.net/AemN5/12/

Comment: Looks good, especially when you add overflow: hidden to body element!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing like this..

chrome requires the image to be displayed atleast until the drag is started.

```
$("[draggable]").on("dragstart", function(e) {
    $("#img1").show();

    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(helper, 50, 50);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#img1").hide();
    },0);
});
```

Comment: dragstart event not working in Magento 2. Have an any idea?